# How can I add a LoopingSelector?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I'm trying to add in my MainPage a "spinner" to make the user select from a list of strings and navigate to the second page. I find out that I can do this through a LoopingSelector but I cannot see any way to add this! 
If I put `<toolkit:LoopingSelector>` in the xaml VS2010 doesn't recognize it.. and I cannot find the .dll in my directories!

Is it ok to use a LoopingSelector or should I use just a listbox?

EDIT:
Btw I found a spinner easier to use, it's the ListPicker! Now I'm trying to implement this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found.. it was "stupid".

I haven't installed the Silverlight Toolkit (available [here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034) for the LoopingSelector) so I couldn't found the .dll.
Now it recognizes the assembly properly!
Let's find how make this thing work..

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
Maybe you are not properly defining "toolkit"?
    <controls:LoopingSelector 
           ItemSize="128,128" 
           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NumberTemplate}">
        <controls:LoopingSelector.DataSource>
            <local:NumbersDataSource />
        </controls:LoopingSelector.DataSource>
    </controls:LoopingSelector>
```

Comment: Don't know, what do you mean with properly defining? Which reference should I add?

Comment: add this dll "Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll"